# Rake 0.9.1 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I have some problems with rake. My gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc1'
gem "rake", "!= 0.9.0"
```

I get this error while trying to migrate:

> [rake --prereqs] rake aborted!
>   uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in `const_missing'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in`'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in`'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:20:in `require'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rake-0.9.1/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:20:in`'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `require'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in`'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:16:in `load'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:16:in`block in '
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in`'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in`block in initialize_tasks'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:182:in `call'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:182:in`each'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:182:in `load_tasks'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/engine.rb:391:in`load_tasks'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:102:in `load_tasks'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:28:in`method_missing'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/Dropbox/Development/Rails/craffft/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in`load'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in`block in load_rakefile'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in`load_rakefile'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
>   /Users/nachtmeister/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake:35:in`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Rake 0.8.7.  Rake basically broke Rails with a backward-incompatible change.  I have my Gemfile with `rake '0.8.7'`.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. I used 0.9.1 because I thought this error was fixed. :/

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using `bundle exec rake`, which will allow you to have both rake 0.8.7 and 0.9.1 installed, if you need 0.9.1.